Change in .launch.py file is not applied when I've changed .launch.py file in ros2 foxy environment
[Situation]
As mentioned at the title, I have changed some code in microstrain_inertial/microstrain_inertial_examples/launch/cv7_launch.py
provided by microstrain github page.
But when I launched the file, changes were not applied.
So I deleted build/ install/ log/ folder in my workspace and build again with command 'colcon build' and the changes were applied.
[Question]
What I know is that unlike c++, we don't have to build again for python. But I don't know what is the problem. Is it related with build option? such as colcon build vs colcon build --symlink-install
Thanks for watching!

Indeed if you use symlink your python (and other) files will always be synchronized between the source and install directories.
Even for C++ code this option is useful as you just need to rebuild with make or cmake, avoiding custom call to colcon.

Thanks for your reply!!
